# Ionic build can only be run in an Ionic project directory

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
[ERROR] Sorry! ionic build can only be run in an Ionic project directory.
```

When I am already in the project directory.

I am trying to build an existing ionic project not sure about the version used but as per some suggestions from fellow SO user, it is done using ionic v3+.

Ionic info:

cli packages: (C:\Users\Administrator.Dryad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

System:

```
Node : v8.11.3
npm  : 6.1.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Directory structure:
[image]

Comment: Is www folder present in your directory structure?

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar no there is no `www` folder instead there is `platform_www` folder.

Comment: create an empty folder and run ionic serve or try build on android device.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Directory structure shows android build folder, it's not ionic project structure. Can you share screenshot for project structure?

Comment: Ohh what is it? Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by screenshot for project structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174225/discussion-between-pradnya-sinalkar-and-arti).

Comment: what is the directory path you are in?

Comment: The screenshot shows it is android build folder, not the ionic project.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting above error because you are executing ionic run command at wrong path. You first need to set your ionic **project path correctly in command prompt**, then execute the specific ionic command to successfully run your project.

Also the above screenshot is for some older version of ionic android platform folder which is located in project_name/platforms/android (Running command here will not run the project).

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can build the project? But it is ionic project only right? Or could it be phonegap proj?

Comment: Is this the only folder you have for this project?? Yes it's Ionic project.

Comment: Thanks, but why doesn't it build then?

Comment: The screenshot you have provided is only for android project. Is this the only folder you have?? To build this project you need to have the main ionic project folder. Ionic project folder will look just like the screenshot Pradnya Sinalkar has provided you in chat.

Comment: I dont have any other files. That is all what I have.

Comment: what if I create a new project and copy paste www folder form assets folder to the newly created ionic project folder then it will work? Any other way I can build the project with what I have?

Comment: No it will not work. Android platform folder is auto created from ionic code which it seems that you do not have. You need to have the ionic code to run the project.